# How to find the difference between the son's and mother's age if it(ages of son and mother) is reversible for a total of 8 times?

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, gcd-and-lcm, python

There is a quiz question for which I need to write a python code. I don't need help for the code but this is what I need help with.

A son had recently visited his mom and found out that the two digits that form his age (eg :24) when reversed form his mother's age (eg: 42). Later he goes back to his place and finds out that this whole 'age' reversed process occurs 6 times. And if they (mom + son) were lucky it would happen again in future for two more times.
So we have a total of 8 times when this would occur. The actual question is how old is the son at present ? **I don't need help with that** , ***I am trying to figure out the age difference*** which in turn will lead to me the present age and based on that I could write my code.

**Observation**: If you take any two-digit number and switch the digits, the
difference between the two numbers is a multiple of 9.In particular, the difference is 9 times the difference between the two digits.

**But how do I figure out this age difference ?**

Comment: Your Question is unclear as to what exactly you want to ask?

Comment: Surely if you can use code, you can brute force different age differences and find one that works?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  are, say, $3$ and $30$ reverses of each other?  If not, then I guess $13,31$ is the first one that makes sense...but the "occurs $6$ times" bit is hard to understand in that context...

Comment: @lulu yes 3 and 30 are suppose to be considered reverse of each other

Comment: Ok, well then $2,20$ works as a starting pair.  But you should edit your post for clarity.  I just guessed at the $3,30$ reversal.

Comment: $3$ and $30$ can not occur $7$ more times. As digit reversals can only occure every $11$ years. and $3+77 \ne 7(10)$ and $30 +77 \ne (10)7$.

Comment: But we haven't considered that if the birthdays are months apart we could have one is $k$ years older in age $(10a + b) + k = 10m + n$ while the other is $k+1$ years older in age $(10b + a) + k+1 = 10n + m$.

Comment: From the givens it seems that this event occurs $6$ times in  anticipated lifetimes of both. This year we are on the fourth time. It is unclear how you arrive at $8$ times.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect you would start with the son's age at the first time when their age swaps were possible. For instance, suppose the son was $12$ years old. Then his mom was $21$ years old. So, your code should age the son and see how many times their ages reverse until the mom would have a 3 digit age. If it occurs eight times, then report the sixth time and you are done. Otherwise, try $13$ for the son and $31$ for the mom. Etc.

I think the answer is the mom was $9$ when she had her son. The son is $67$ and the mom is $76$. Eww.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}\text{Mom} & \text{Son} & \text{Number} \\ \hline 21 & 12 & 1 \\ 32 & 23 & 2 \\ 43 & 34 & 3 \\ 54 & 45 & 4 \\ 65 & 56 & 5 \\ 76 & 67 & 6 \\ 87 & 78 & 7 \\ 98 & 89 & 8\end{array}$$

Comment: how do i know at what number to start with for the son's age ?

Comment: Start with the first two digit number where the mom's age is larger than the son's age. 12 is the first time that happens.

Comment: don't forget that 03 and 30 are reverses of each other.  remember zfill method in python

Comment: Fair enough. Then as lulu stated, the first time it occurred was when the son was 2. He is 57, mom is 75.

Comment: Is no-one going to point out the mother being 9 years old when the son was born is disgusting!

Comment: It depends on how a year is defined. In Hinduism a day of Brahma is quite a long period.

Answer (score 0):

He is his mother's age and presently he is $66$.

Comment: It seems unlikely that he would be the same age as his mother.

Comment: How do we find approach this question so as to find the difference ?

Comment: They cannot be the same age because then there would be three more times when their ages are reversible, not two more times.

Comment: I agree with your statement, but it assumes that _lucky_ means they will live to 99. I simply had a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The first time it happen was when the son was $10a  + b$ and then mother was $10b + a$.  In $k$ years it happened again and the son was $10a + b+k$ and then mother was $10b + a + k$.

Case 1:  $b+k$ and $a+k$ are both under $10$

Then $a+k =a$ and $b+k = b$ and $k =0$.  That's .... a loophole. The implicit assumption was $k > 0$.

Case 2:  $b+k \ge 10$ but $a + k < 10$ so $k \le 9$ and $b+k \le 19$.  So the son is $10(a+1) + (b+k-10)$ and the mother is $10b + (a+k)$ and $a+k = a+1$ and $(b+k-10) =b$ so $k=1$ and $k=10$.  That's impossible.

Case 3: $b+k < 10$ but $a+ k \ge 10$.  Same problem as Case 2.  $(a+k-10)=a$ but $b+1 = b+k$.

Case 4:  $b+k \ge 10$ and $a+k \ge 10$.

Case 4a:  There is a $j$ so that $10j \le b+k < 10(j+1)$ and $10j \le a+k < 10(j+1)$

Son is $10(a+j) + (b+k-10j)$ and Mother is $10(b+k) + (a+k-10j)$ so $a+j = a+k-10j$ and $k = 11j$.

Now a bit of common sense: This can not proceed to three digits.  The reverse of $1xy$ is $yx1$ and we can assume $200$ is beyond the range of human longevity.  So if the son *is* the reverse of a three digit mother, then they are both $1x1$ and are the same age which is obviously impossible.

SO for this to occur $8$ times $j$ must be $1$.

For this to occur $8$ times then $8$th time we will have the son $10a+b+77$ and the mother is $10b+a+77$ and as we can *never* have a Case 2: or Case 3 we need $a+7 < 10$ and $b+7<10$ So $a<3$ and $b< 3$.  As the mother is older $b > a$.  So if $b=2$ and $a=1$ then the mother was $21$ and the boy was $12$ and that is just plain GROSS!!!!

So I'm guessing a first digit of $0$ has to be acceptable.  So this occurred at when the son was $2$ and the mother was $20$.

....

To really complete this I should consinder $b+k < 10j \le a+k$ (and vice versa)

And we should also consider that in $k$ years and some months. That the son (or mother) may have had $k$ birthdays the other could have had $k+1$ birthdays.

Comment: In that case you add $k$ to $b$ but that in bigger than $10$ so you carry.  $10a + b < 10(a+1) \le 10a + b+k$.  So the first digit of $10a + b + k$ is $(a+1)$ and the second digit is $b+k-10$.  And $10a + b + k = 10(a+1) + (b+k -10)$.  For example:  If for example $10 a + b = 56$ and $k=8$ then $56 + 8 = 5*10 + (6+8) = 5*10 + 14$.  But there is no such number as $5(14)$. Instead the number $(5+1)*10 + (14-10)= 6*10+4 = 64$.  THis is *basic* first grade arithmetic of borrowing and carrying.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the age digit of mom as 'xy' then son will 'yx'; difference in there age is c

10x+y=x+10y+c

(x-y)=c/9

(x-y)=n

(n+9-TE,n)={7,6}=76(21,32,43,54,65,_76,87,98)

TE=it's 8 in your case

n=6th in your case

I don't explain well so i had removed all Massy things this is the final outcome I found.using above equation you can find any event age even total occurrence chance from 8 to something else